# Adding a View as Select - Item to DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, nopcommerce

I've made a controller with two ActionResult. GetData returns a List of objects to the View GAStatistics.cshtml. I've added a @Html.DropDownList to GASTatistics.cshtml and I want to populate this dropdownlist with GetData - ActionResult and GetData.cshtml.

I also have a list model called GAStatisticsListModel which contains DateTime StartDate, EndDate and List AvailableGAStatistics. I'm thinking I have to add the view "GetData.cshtml" or ActionResult GetData AvailableGAStatistics.

I have also made a ListModel and added a DropDownList to the view.  How do I add GetData.cshtml as an item to the menu?

My best guess is I need to create an ActionResult that adds CreateCompaniesList to model.AvailableGaStatistics in GAStatisticsListModel but I have no clue.

Controller:

```
public class GAStatisticsController : Controller
{
    //GET: /ShopStatistics/

    public ActionResult GetData() // <-- this result as a menu item
    {
        return Json(CreateCompaniesList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult GAStatistics()
    {
        return View(new GAStatisticsListModel());
    }

    private IEnumerable<GAStatistics> CreateCompaniesList()
    {
        //SOME CODE........................

        List<GAStatistics> ListGaVisitors = new List<GAStatistics>();

        foreach (var row in d.Rows)
        {
            GAStatistics GaVisits = new GAStatistics(row[0], row[1]);
            ListGaVisitors.Add(GaVisits);
        }

        return ListGaVisitors;
    }
}
```

(I want to add the ActionResult GetData to AvailableGAStatistics)
ListModel:

```
public class GAStatisticsListModel : BaseNopModel
{
    public GAStatisticsListModel()
    {
        AvailableGAStatistics = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.ShopStatistics.List.StartDate")]
    [UIHint("DateNullable")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.ShopStatistics.List.EndDate")]
    [UIHint("DateNullable")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.GAStatistics.GAStatistics.AvailableGAStatistics")]
    public int GAStatisticsId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableGAStatistics { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model GAStatisticsListModel

@using Nop.Admin.Models.GAStatistics;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using Nop.Admin.Controllers;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GAStatistics";
    Layout = "~/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<table class="adminContent">
    <tr>
        @*<td>@Html.Action("GAnalyticsService", "GAStatistics")</td>*@
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StartDate):
        </td>
    <td class="adminData">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.EndDate):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.GAStatisticsId ):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.DropDownList("GAStatisticsId", Model.AvailableGAStatistics)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I try this:

```
public ActionResult GAStatistics()
{
    var model = new GAStatisticsListModel();
    model.AvailableGAStatistics = CreateGAStatisticsReport();
    return View(model);
}
```